# hubot jenkins.coffee where is slack userid stored

Tags: jenkins, coffeescript, slack, hubot

I am not able to fund where the slack user id is stored when hubot replies to a request.  I want hubot to pass that value to jenkins along with the job command.  Tack it onto the request via the params object

```
  robot.respond /j(?:enkins)? build ([\w\.\-_ ]+)(, (.+))?/i, (msg) ->
    jenkinsBuild(msg, false)
```

Is it inside the msg object?

```
jenkinsBuild = (msg, buildWithEmptyParameters) ->
    url = process.env.HUBOT_JENKINS_URL
    job = querystring.escape msg.match[1]
    params = msg.match[3]
    command = if buildWithEmptyParameters then "buildWithParameters" else "build"
    path = if params then "#{url}/job/#{job}/buildWithParameters?#{params}" else "#{url}/job/#{job}/#{command}"

    req = msg.http(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pulled out an answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990762/debugging-printing-in-a-hubot-script#17245534)

slackid is msg.message.user.name